# Что значит это выражение в с#?

Tags: c#

```
return 
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(wb) ? AddressType.InternalAddress : AddressType.ExternalAddress;
```

Comment: Называется тернарный оператор

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Альтернативная форма записи условия if:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(wb))
{
    return AddressType.InternalAddress;
}
else
{
    return AddressType.ExternalAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
return string.IsNullOrEmpty(wb) ? 
   AddressType.InternalAddress : AddressType.ExternalAddress;
```

Если значением переменной `wb` является пустая строка `string.Empty` (или просто `""`) или значение `null` - будет возвращено значение `AddressType.InternalAddress`, в противном случае будет возвращено `AddressType.ExternalAddress`.

Справка MSDN:

1. [Оператор ?: (справочник по C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ty67wk28.aspx)
2. [Метод String.IsNullOrEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)
3. [Поле String.Empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.empty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: то есть  ? это if, а : это else ?

Comment: @olmar102, в случае выполнения условия результатом будет левая сторона выражения, иначе - правая сторона. Да, что-то вроде `if...else`

Answer (score 1):

Если строка `wb` пустая или не инициализирована - вернуть `InternalAddress` иначе вернуть `ExternalAddress`.
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ty67wk28.aspx)